# iPhone Passcode for Powering Off

Tags: iphone, ios, security

I am looking for an option to require a passcode to power off my iPhone. That way, if the phone is lost, the person who finds it cannot simply turn it off, rendering `Find My iPhone` useless. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

In the current OS, this isn't possible. However, there is a jailbreak mod that will accomplish this functionality called [PowerGuard](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=powerguardDp).

[image]

Comment: Has there been any progress from Apple on this? I know this question was asked more than 8 years ago, but this is still relevant.  Is PowerGuard still the best available solution? This seems such a no-brainer functionality that the Android ecosystem has by default, does Apple just want to encourage stealing iPhones for spare parts? So we buy more iPhones lol

Comment: @elegantcomplexity Wouldn't you also need to prevent users from disabling WiFi and Cellular from the Lock Screen?

Comment: @nohillside you can do that now. At least in iOS 15.3, you can go to Settings --> Face ID & Passcode -- Allow Access when Unlocked -- Toggle off Control Center and even toggle off USB Accessories to prevent any tampering with while locked. The only thing I can't do it make it ask me to unlock the iPhone before I power it off.